# Recursive sumNumbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming, sum

My task is: to write a function who calculate (`a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b + 2^2 * b` until it happens `2^(n-1)*b)`, other who calculate (`a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b + 2^2 * b` until it happens `2^(n-2)*b`) and another one who calculate (`a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b + 2^2 * b` until it happens `2^(n-3)*b`).

I have to write a function who calculate sum of the three functions but this function has to accept 3 argument - the numbers `a` `b` `n`!

`n` is always greater than 3!

This is what I have done until this moment:

```hs
findSum :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
findSum a b n
  | a >= 0 && b > 0 && n > 3 = findSum1 a b n + findSum2 a b n + findSum3 a b n
  | otherwise = 0
  where
    findSum1 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
    findSum1 a b n
      | n <= 3 = 0
      | otherwise = a + 2 ^ (n-1) * b + findSum1 a b (n-1)

    findSum2 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
    findSum2 a b n
      | n <= 3 = 0
      | otherwise = a + 2 ^ (n-2) * b + findSum2 a b (n-2)

    findSum3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
    findSum3 a b n
      | n < 0 = 0
      | otherwise = a + 2 ^ (n-3) * b + findSum3 a b (n-3)
```

But It gives me an error:

```
Exception: Negative exponent.
```

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce the problem (i.e. which input produces the reported error)? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 2):

`findSum3` does compare `n < 0` instead of  `n <= 3` in the first clause.
That leads to it trying to calculate `2 ^ (n-3)` with an `n < 3` eventually which results in a negative exponent, and that's not allowed.

Comment: How can i edit the code then. For example is n = 8, it has to happen 8-3=5, I noted that it has to be greater than 3, i cannot be a negative result then.

Comment: How did you solve the problem for the other 2 functions?

Comment: yes, only the third is the problem

Comment: So apply your solution for the first 2 to the 3rd function.

Comment: Actually, it happened with your first answer. But It doesn't work in like these case print $ findSum 5 3 5 (because a = n)